# Making archive with the current date as folder name, and add 1, 2, etc if folder exists

Tags: backup, automated

I'm looking to configure this backup script to take the current day's date and make the directory in a mmddyyyy format, as this will be automated. However, if the directory with that current day already exists (if I needed to do more than one backup on a given day), I want to add -1 or -2, so that it would appear 07072011-3 (if it were the 4th backup being made that day).

is there a simple way to add onto the end of the directory name, +1 for each time it's been written?

Set date/folder name

`today="$ (date +%m%d%Y)"`

`mkdir /home/user/backup/$today`

Check if dir exists

`if [ ! -d /home/user/backup/$today ]`

`then`

`echo Directory already exists ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use DDMMYYYY ? Using YYYYMMDD is easier as the default sort order for `ls` will then correctly sort the newest to the top.

You can also extend the date idea to use time e.g.

```
today=$( date +%Y%m%d%H)
```

to get YYYYMMDDHH and you can even add  %M and %S if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to stick with the format you have selected, you could do something like the following:

```
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
folder=$today
i=0
while [ -e /home/user/$folder ]
do
  echo "${folder} exists";
  i=$(( $i + 1 ))
  folder="${today}-${i}"
done
echo $folder;
```